# Put my code into methods

Tags: c#, methods

I have my completed code but it is quite long and I believe it can be put into methods, I do not know how to do methods and if anyone can help me put it into a method it would be greatly appreciated, thank you

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(); //this string is what is used to generate a random number
    int lottery = 0; //an integer named lottery. It is set to 0 since the program doesn't so it can initialise as any random number



    for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
    {
        lottery = rnd.Next(1, 49);
        lblLot1.Text = lottery.ToString();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
    {
        lottery = rnd.Next(1, 49);
        lblLot2.Text = lottery.ToString();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
    {
        lottery = rnd.Next(1, 49);
        lblLot3.Text = lottery.ToString();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
    {
        lottery = rnd.Next(1, 49);
        lblLot4.Text = lottery.ToString();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
    {
        lottery = rnd.Next(1, 49);
        lblLot5.Text = lottery.ToString();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
    {
        lottery = rnd.Next(1, 49);
        lblLot6.Text = lottery.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code allows duplicates, you cant have duplicate numbers in lottery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044897/lottery-number-generator-c-sharp - I thought your name looked familiar

Answer (score 3):

No need for a method per label. Just a for loop will do:

```
foreach (Label lblLot in new Label[] {lblLot1, lblLot2, lblLot3, lblLot4, lblLot5, ...} )
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
    {
        int lottery = rnd.Next(1, 49);
        lblLot.Text = lottery.ToString();
    }
}
```

Also, the for loop seems strange to me. You want to set the value of the label once, right. If you want to change it every X seconds, you would need a time or so. Not it just freezes the application until it has gone through the for loop 50 times and then shows the last value on screen.

So my guess it this should do:

```
foreach (Label lblLot in new Label[] {lblLot1, lblLot2, lblLot3, lblLot4, lblLot5, ...} )
{
    int lottery = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    lblLot.Text = lottery.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you for that it is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your code is very very strange. Why do you set the value of **each `TextBox` 49 times**? Only the **last** value will be visible!

So here is what you probably wanted to do (6 out of 49):

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] lottery = Enumerable.Range(1, 49).OrderBy(i => r.Next()).Take(6).ToArray();
lblLot1.Text = lottery[0].ToString();
lblLot2.Text = lottery[1].ToString();
lblLot3.Text = lottery[2].ToString();
lblLot4.Text = lottery[3].ToString();
lblLot5.Text = lottery[4].ToString();
lblLot6.Text = lottery[5].ToString();
```

- `Enumerable.Range()` creates a sequence of numbers from 6 to 49.
- This sequence is shuffled by `OrderBy` using random numbers
- then an array is created from the first six numbers in that sequence
- finally the textboxes are filled with these six values

By creating one shuffled sequence and taking the first six, you avoid duplicates. In your code, you could come up with `1, 17, 17, 19, 29, 35`, which is not a valid lottery number sequence.

If you want the numbers to be sorted, you may add an `OrderBy(i => i)` between the `Take(6)` and `ToArray()`. So only the chosen six get sorted again:

```
int[] lottery = Enumerable.Range(1, 49).OrderBy(i => r.Next()).Take(6).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
```

Comment: My program is a random lottery number generator, it is generating the numbers between 1 and 49

Comment: @glenGriffiths your `for` loops are unnecessary. The textbox will only display the value from the _last_ iteration. Since your method blocks the UI thread, the previous 48 values won't be visible at all. Give my code a try and you'll see it does what you want.

Comment: @glenGriffiths so a pattern with duplicates (like "1,2,3,3,4,4") is valid for you? Then I misunderstood you, our lottery works different :)